# calc() size of the current object

Tags: css, calc

For some reason when I am using margin auto on each side to centre the element it's not working. I am assuming it's because I am using percentages and whatnot.

I tried to use calc() a bit more, but since the contents of the element I want to centre may vary over time, I want to try and make it always be centred.

I am doing this with the following: `margin: 0px calc(50% - 554px / 2)  0px calc(50% - 554px / 2);`

The current width of the element is 554px. So dividing it by 2 and removing that from 50% of the parent element will give it the margin on each side that it needs to be centred.

The problem is, the size may vary in the future so I want to replace 554 with an automatic width if that makes sense. So basically I want to haveit like this: `margin: 0px calc(50% - width / 2)  0px calc(50% - width / 2);` with width being the current element width of course. How can I do this?

I have tried looking this up online, sorry for wasting your time with may seem like a simple question.

```css
div#game {
 margin-top: 50px;
 width: 80%;
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
}

div#gameselect {
 margin: 0px calc(50% - 554px / 2)  0px calc(50% - 554px / 2);
 display: inline-block;
}

div.gameselect {
 float: left;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
}

p.lefttri {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-bottom: 30px solid #FF4444;
 border-left: 20px solid transparent;
 float: left;
}

p#test {
 font-family: title;
 font-size: 30px;
 line-height: 24px;
 height: 24px;
 color: white;
 padding: 3px 11px 3px 0px;
 background-color: #FF4444;
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
}

p.righttri {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-top: 30px solid #FF4444;
 border-right: 20px solid transparent;
 float: left;
 z-index: 0;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
  <div id="gameselect">
   <a href="https://www.google.com"><div class="gameselect">
    <p class="lefttri"></p>
     <p id="test">
     ONE
     </p>
    <p class="righttri"></p>
   </div></a>

   <div class="gameselect gs2">
    <p class="lefttri"></p>
     <p id="test">
     TWO
     </p>
    <p class="righttri"></p>
   </div>

   <div class="gameselect gs3">
    <p class="lefttri"></p>
     <p id="test">
     THREE
     </p>
    <p class="righttri"></p>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Show us what you have now that isn't working. Give us a [mcve] of what you have so far.

Comment: I added it @MichaelCoker I don't know why it would make a difference because my question is pretty well explained...

Comment: Thanks. It's minimal effort on your part to provide *all of the relevant code* that isn't working, and that way we aren't guessing at what part of the problem is from just the single bit of CSS you've provided. Giving us a working demo allows us to make suggestions that we can *verify* work without going back and forth guessing at fixes where you update it behind the scenes and let us know if it's working or not.

Comment: *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to hard code `554px` in when calculating those margins, you could just apply `width: 554px` to `#gameselect`, then your `margin: auto;` would work. But it isn't 554px on my side - that width is going to vary depending on the user's browser, and as you can see it doesn't truly center the element. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wJpNLK Or who knows, maybe this will be centered on your side now.

But there are a number of other ways you could center this content. `display: flex; justify-content: center` on `#gameselect` does it fluidly without having to specify fixed widths like that, which you want to avoid.

```css
div#game {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 80%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

div#gameselect {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

div.gameselect {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

p.lefttri {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 30px solid #FF4444;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  float: left;
}

p#test {
  font-family: title;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  color: white;
  padding: 3px 11px 3px 0px;
  background-color: #FF4444;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

p.righttri {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 30px solid #FF4444;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  float: left;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="gameselect">
  <a href="https://www.google.com">
    <div class="gameselect">
      <p class="lefttri"></p>
      <p id="test">
        ONE
      </p>
      <p class="righttri"></p>
    </div>
  </a>

  <div class="gameselect gs2">
    <p class="lefttri"></p>
    <p id="test">
      TWO
    </p>
    <p class="righttri"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="gameselect gs3">
    <p class="lefttri"></p>
    <p id="test">
      THREE
    </p>
    <p class="righttri"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```